# TagSetDelayed for spotting zero derivatives

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, assignment

I am trying to implement my own differential operator, `d[arg_, var_]`,
that computes the derivative of `arg` w.r.t. `var`.
Now, I need to `teach' Mathematica about the key properties of that operator.
In particular, I want it to remove all derivatives that are obviously zero because `arg` is independent of `var`.
My attempt is as follows

```
Clear[d];
d /: d[arg_, var_] := 0 /; (SameQ[D[arg, var], 0]);
```

At first, this rule seemed to work fine, because I got

```
d[x,x]
   ---> d[x,x]
d[x,y]
   ---> 0
```

Yet, if I now stack up the derivatives, the rule seems to be incorrectly applied.
Indeed, I got

```
d[d[x+y,x],y]
   ---> 0
```

which is incorrect.

To investigate the origin of this strange behaviour, I modified the previous rule to also print its arguments when it is being applied, as such:

```
Clear[d];
d /: d[arg_, var_] := (Print["| ",arg, " | ", var]; 0) /; (SameQ[D[arg, var], 0]);
```

For the same test as before I got

```
d[d[x+y,x],y]
   ---> | #1 | #2
        | d[x+y,x] | y
        0
```

It seems therefore that the rule is being used once with the pure arguments `{#1,#2}`, which is likely the reason for the bug encountered.

Where does this strange evaluation come from?
And how should one fix the `TagSetDelayed` for the rule to be applied as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that one expression is free of another, I would use

```
d /: d[arg_, var_] := 0 /; FreeQ[arg, var]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do the trick. Would you have a feeling why my previous attempt was failing?

Comment: I've had a quick look at `Trace[d[d[x + y, x], y]]`.  I believe that Mathematica tries to derive rules for the derivatives of functions from the definitions you give.  In this case, (I think) it looks at your definition of `d`, ignores the condition, and concludes that its derivative is zero.